# Set the FROM field when replying based on either the TO field or the emails Category

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange-2010

Is there a way in Outlook 2007 to set it up so that if a user is part of a distribution group and receives an email sent to that group, that when they click reply, it puts into the FROM field the address of the distribution group?

At the moment the user has to manually set the FROM field every time they are replying to an email sent to the distribution group.

If you can set the default from address based on the emails category I could setup inbox rules to categorise emails as they come in?

I don't really want to have to look into writing a plugin for outlook to do this, hoping there is something built in.

Comment: In the end I couldn't find a way to do this by tweaking the settings in Outlook, so I went ahead and wrote an Outlook Add-In. Once i've fully tested it and know it's working i'll do a blog post on it and try and remember to come back here to post the link.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Outlook simply can not be configured in this advanced way.